# Access the Visual Studio Web Server Using a Different User Context

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Does anyone know if there is a way to allow access to the Visual Studio Web Server from alternate user accounts?

My application relies heavily on integrated authentication and I'd like to do regular testing of different accounts with different permissions. I had thought it would be as simple as debugging the app from Visual Studio, running `runas /user:domain/some.other.user "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` and then copying the URL (including port) of the currently executing application on the VS web server to the newly launched IE instance. However, when you do that the VS web server throws up a nice little 403 page.

What I don't know is if the 403 is because I'm trying to access from a different account than is running VS (I suspect this is the case) or because the integrated authentication isn't working right (though it works fine under the same account as is running VS and when deployed to IIS). Any tips?